# Custom RecyclerView with list of subject classes inside Issue with onClickListener of SubjectSchedule

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I need to display a `recyclerview` of subjects with subclasses of subject schedules

My issue is the `onClickListener` of subject schedule it must be a single-select and the selected one must be highlighted and set to the default the previous selected item.

how can i achieve that? Below is the structure of my object class

- subjectID
- subjectName
- List(SubjectSchedule)

  - scheduleID
  - subjectName
  - professor
  - room
  - unit

    ```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

     final Resources res = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources();
     final Subject note = subjectList.get(position);

      holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

      holder.tvSubject.setText(note.getSubjectName());

      if(note.getSubjectScheduleList() != null){
    //dito nagagawa ng dynamic

    for(final SubjectSchedule ss: note.getSubjectScheduleList()){

        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);

        layoutParams.setMargins(8,8,8,8);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);

        String schedule = ss.getTimeStart()+ " - " + ss.getTimeEnd()+" "+ss.getDay();

        //Create base layout
        final LinearLayout llBase = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        llBase.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        llBase.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        if(ss.isSelected()){
            llBase.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }else{
            llBase.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }

            //create first row
            LinearLayout llRow1 = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            llRow1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            llRow1.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            llBase.addView(llRow1);

                // Create TextView
                TextView subjectName = new TextView(mContext);
                subjectName.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                subjectName.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
                subjectName.setText(ss.getSubjectName());
                llRow1.addView(subjectName);

                TextView unit = new TextView(mContext);
                unit.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                unit.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
                unit.setText(ss.getUnit());
                llRow1.addView(unit);

        //create 2nd row
        LinearLayout llRow2 = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        llRow2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        llRow2.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
        llBase.addView(llRow2);

            // Create TextView
            TextView professor = new TextView(mContext);
            professor.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            professor.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            professor.setText(ss.getSection());
            llRow2.addView(professor);

            TextView section = new TextView(mContext);
            section.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            section.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            section.setText(ss.getProfessor());
            llRow2.addView(section);

        //create 3rd row
        LinearLayout llRow3 = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        llRow3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        llBase.addView(llRow3);

            // Create TextView
            TextView room = new TextView(mContext);
            room.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            room.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            room.setText(ss.getRoom());
            llRow3.addView(room);

            TextView sched = new TextView(mContext);
            sched.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            sched.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            sched.setText(schedule);
            llRow3.addView(sched);

        holder.layoutSubjectItem.addView(llBase);

        llBase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ss.setSelected(true);
                notifyItemChanged(ss.hashCode());
                llBase.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

                changeOthers(ss,note.getSubjectScheduleList(),llBase);

                SelectedSubjectSchedule pinili = new SelectedSubjectSchedule(
                    note.getSubjectID(),
                    ss.getSchedID(),
                    ss.getSubjectName(),
                    ss.getProfessor(),
                    ss.getRoom(),
                    ss.getUnit(),
                    ss.getSection(),
                    ss.getTimeStart(),
                    ss.getTimeEnd(),
                    ss.getDay());

                if(selectedSubjectScheduleList.size() == 0){
                    selectedSubjectScheduleList.add(pinili);
                }else{

                    for(int k=0; k<selectedSubjectScheduleList.size(); k++){
                        SelectedSubjectSchedule item = selectedSubjectScheduleList.get(k);

                        if(item.getSubjectID().equals(note.getSubjectID())){
                            selectedSubjectScheduleList.remove(k);
                        }
                    }

                    if(!selectedSubjectScheduleList.contains(pinili)) {
                        selectedSubjectScheduleList.add(pinili);
                    }
                }

                Log.i("OOOO","Selected Subjects");
                Iterator<SelectedSubjectSchedule> j = selectedSubjectScheduleList.iterator();
                while (j.hasNext()) {
                    SelectedSubjectSchedule s = j.next();
                    Log.i("OOOO",s.getSubjectID()+"-"+s.getSubjectName());
                }

            }
        });
        }

        }

        }
    ```

---

> **I use this function to update the list**

```
private void changeOthers(SubjectSchedule ss, List<SubjectSchedule> subjectScheduleList, LinearLayout llBase) {

    for(SubjectSchedule item: subjectScheduleList){
        if(!item.equals(ss)){
            item.setSelected(false);
            notifyItemChanged(item.hashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here..

Comment: @VedPrakash i updated the description